# SQLite select distinct join query how to

Tags: join, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I'm trying to build a query.  The table column I need to retrieve is iEDLID from the table below :

[image]

Right now all I have to go on is a known iEventID from the table below :

[image]

And the the nClientLocationID from the table below.

[image]

So the requirements are I need to get current iEDLID to write, lookup from tblEventDateLocations for dEventDate and the tblLocation.nClientLocationID based on the tblLocations.iLocationID I already have and event selected on this screen.

So I would need a query that does a "SELECT DISTINCT  table EventDateLocations.iEDLID FROM tblEventDateLocations ...."
So basically from another query I have the iEventID I need, and I have the event ID i need but where the dEventDate=(select date('now')) I need to retrieve the iEventDateID from table EventDates.iEventDateID to use on the table EventDateLocations

this is the point where I'm trying to wrap my head around the joins for this query and the syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want this:

```
select distinct edl.iEDLDID
from
  tblEventDateLocations edl
  join tblEventDates ed on edl.EventDateId = ed.EventDateId
where
  ed.EventId = ?
  and ed.dEventDate = date('now')
  and edl.nClientLocationID = ?
```

where the `?` of course represent the known event ID and location ID parameters.

Since `nClientLocationId` appears on table `tblEventDateLocations` you do not need to join table `tblLocations` unless you want to filter out results whose location ID does not appear in that table.

Comment: Ok I was about to say the same exact thing.  I'm too used to doing the literal queries and thinking of them in that order. That's an excellent answer...

Comment: One more question could I use limit 1 to return just one row?

Comment: Yes, SQLite supports the `LIMIT` clause, and there's no reason why it wouldn't work with this query.  Whether using it here is actually appropriate, on the other hand, is not a question I can answer -- it depends heavily on the meaning of your data and your intended use of the query result.  A key question to ask yourself is whether it makes sense for your purposes to arbitrarily choose one result over the others.

Comment: Well I will need one result to use throughout the app.  Versus a list of ID's I need one that would be used and inserted and updated in the database.

Comment: I guess what I need to ask is is there a better way to make sure I only return one result based on the date, EventID, EventDateID, and nClientLocationID?

Comment: @Bob'sBurgers, yes, that *is* the question to ask.  The answer, however -- and my point -- is that the structure of your data does not appear to inherently provide a unique result, so if you need a unique result then likely you have a design problem to solve.  Probably you need to define more keys; possibly you need to define some additional constraints, perhaps you need a deeper re-design of your data.